# Find all points where function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find all points where function

$$\frac{|z^2|\bar{z}}{e^{\bar{z}}}$$ is holomorphic.

First thought was to check C-R equations, but it turned out to be a bad idea. It would take ages. There must be a simpler way. Can you point me in a good direction? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED** with thanks to Daniel Fischer: $f$ is complex differentiable only at $z=0$ and $z=2$. You can write $f(z)=\dfrac{|z|^2\bar z}{e^{\bar z}} = \underbrace{z}_{g(z)}\cdot\underbrace{\dfrac{\bar z^2}{e^{\bar z}}}_{h(z)}$. Using $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$, we have the characterization that $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z$ if and only if $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z} = 0$ at $z$. (Many texts require that the function be complex differentiable on a neighborhood of $z_0$ in order to call the function holomorphic *at* $z_0$.)

Now use the product rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}(g(z)h(z)) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar z} h(z) + g(z) \frac{\partial h}{\partial\bar z}.$$
Since $g$ is holomorphic, the first term vanishes. The second term vanishes when $\bar z = 0$ or $2$, hence at $z=0$ and $z=2$.

Comment: I must nit-pick, the function is nowhere holomorphic. It is complex differentiable at $0$ (and at $2$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}} (\overline{z}^2e^{-\overline{z}}) = \overline{z}(2-\overline{z})e^{-\overline{z}}$), but holomorphic at a point means complex differentiable on a neighbourhood of that point.

Comment: @DanielF: Well, this is a matter of convention. To me, holomorphic means *complex differentiable*, whereas complex analytic entails local behavior ... But I was sloppy about $z=2$. It would seem Wikipedia sides with you, as, I'm sure, do many books.